# How to trigger a watchdog when a disc is inserted?

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

I am working on a Python DVD ripping script and was having issues using Watchdog. How could I trigger my script whenever a DVD Drive gets inserted? The examples given are based on knowing the drive path, but DVDs are removable. If anyone has ideas or thoughts on this please let me know. Here's my test code if that helps anyone.

```
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
# calling test functions
event_handler.on_created = lambda : print("created")
event_handler.on_deleted = lambda : print("deleted")
event_handler.on_modified = lambda : print("modified")
event_handler.on_moved = lambda : print("moved")

# event_handler.on_created = on_created
# event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
# event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
# event_handler.on_moved = on_moved

path = "D://"
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    print("Monitoring")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
    print("Terminating")
observer.join()
```

Here's the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daren/Documents/01 PYTHON/DVD Auto Ripper/watcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    observer.start()
  File "C:\Users\Daren\Documents\01 PYTHON\DVD Auto Ripper\venv\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 256, in start
    emitter.start()
  File "C:\Users\Daren\Documents\01 PYTHON\DVD Auto Ripper\venv\lib\site-packages\watchdog\utils\__init__.py", line 93, in start
    self.on_thread_start()
  File "C:\Users\Daren\Documents\01 PYTHON\DVD Auto Ripper\venv\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\read_directory_changes.py", line 67, in on_thread_start
    self._handle = get_directory_handle(self.watch.path)
  File "C:\Users\Daren\Documents\01 PYTHON\DVD Auto Ripper\venv\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 316, in get_directory_handle
    return CreateFileW(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, WATCHDOG_FILE_SHARE_FLAGS,
  File "C:\Users\Daren\Documents\01 PYTHON\DVD Auto Ripper\venv\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\winapi.py", line 112, in _errcheck_handle
    raise ctypes.WinError()
PermissionError: [WinError 21] The device is not ready.
```

Answer (score 1):

I finshed the Auto Ripping script and here is the watcher part of the code if it helps anyone.

**I named this auto_rip.py**

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
import subprocess
import logging
from dataclasses import dataclass
import ctypes
from typing import List
import json

@dataclass
class Drive:
    letter: str
    label: str
    drive_type: str

    @property
    def is_removable(self) -> bool:
        return self.drive_type == 'Removable Disk'

    @property
    def is_compact_disc(self) -> bool:
        return self.drive_type == 'Compact Disc'

    def eject(self):
        ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW(f"open {self.letter.upper()}: type cdaudio alias {self.letter.lower()}_drive", None, 0, None)
        ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW(f"set {self.letter.lower()}_drive door open", None, 0, None)

def list_drives() -> List[Drive]:
        """
        Get a list of drives using WMI
        :return: list of drives
        """
        proc = subprocess.run(
                    args=[
                        'powershell',
                                    '-noprofile',
                                    '-command',
                                    'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object deviceid,volumename,drivetype | ConvertTo-Json'
                    ],
                    text=True,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        if proc.returncode != 0 or not proc.stdout.strip():
            logger.error('Failed to enumerate drives')
            return []
        devices = json.loads(proc.stdout)

        drive_types = {
            0: 'Unknown',
            1: 'No Root Directory',
            2: 'Removable Disk',
            3: 'Local Disk',
            4: 'Network Drive',
            5: 'Compact Disc',
            6: 'RAM Disk',
        }

        return [Drive(
                    letter=d['deviceid'],
                    label=d['volumename'],
                    drive_type=drive_types[d['drivetype']]
        ) for d in devices]
```

*main.py* *It's important that its called that unless you run it in a thread*

```
import json
import logging
from typing import Callable, List

import win32api, win32con, win32gui
from auto_rip import Drive, list_drives 

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class DeviceListener:
    """
    Listens to Win32 `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages
    and trigger a callback when a device has been plugged in or out

    See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange
    """
    WM_DEVICECHANGE_EVENTS = {
        0x0019: ('DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED','A request to change the current configuration (dock or undock) has been canceled.'),
        0x0018: ('DBT_CONFIGCHANGED', 'The current configuration has changed, due to a dock or undock.'),
        0x8006: ('DBT_CUSTOMEVENT', 'A custom event has occurred.'),
        0x8000: ('DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL', 'A device or piece of media has been inserted and is now available.'),
        0x8001: ('DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE', 'Permission is requested to remove a device or piece of media. Any application can deny this request and cancel the removal.'),
        0x8002: ('DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED', 'A request to remove a device or piece of media has been canceled.'),
        0x8004: ('DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE', 'A device or piece of media has been removed.'),
        0x8003: ('DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING', 'A device or piece of media is about to be removed. Cannot be denied.'),
        0x8005: ('DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC', 'A device-specific event has occurred.'),
        0x0007: ('DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED', 'A device has been added to or removed from the system.'),
        0x0017: ('DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG', 'Permission is requested to change the current configuration (dock or undock).'),
        0xFFFF: ('DBT_USERDEFINED', 'The meaning of this message is user-defined.'),
    }

    def __init__(self, on_change: Callable[[List[Drive]], None]):
        self.on_change = on_change

    def _create_window(self):
        """
        Create a window for listening to messages
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window#creating-the-window

        See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww

        :return: window hwnd
        """
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.lpfnWndProc = self._on_message
        wc.lpszClassName = self.__class__.__name__
        wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        class_atom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        return win32gui.CreateWindow(class_atom, self.__class__.__name__, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, wc.hInstance, None)

    def start(self):
        logger.info('Listening to drive changes')
        hwnd = self._create_window()
        logger.debug(f'Created listener window with hwnd={hwnd:x}')
        logger.debug('Listening to messages')
        win32gui.PumpMessages()

    def _on_message(self, hwnd: int, msg: int, wparam: int, lparam: int):
        if msg != win32con.WM_DEVICECHANGE:
            return 0
        event, description = self.WM_DEVICECHANGE_EVENTS[wparam]
        logger.debug(f'Received message: {event} = {description}')
        if event in ('DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL'):#, 'DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE'):
            # logger.info('A device has been plugged in (or out)')
            logger.info('A device has been plugged in')
            self.on_change(self.list_drives())
        return 0

def on_devices_changed(drives: List[Drive]):
    removable_drives = [d for d in drives if d.is_compact_disc]
    # removable_drives = [d for d in drives if d.is_removable] # gets all removable drives
    logger.debug(f'Connected removable drives: {removable_drives}')
    for drive in removable_drives:
        # TODO make trigger for my code
        logger.debug(f'Drive: {drive.letter} is type: {drive.drive_type}')
        backup(drive)


def backup(drive: Drive, backup_drive="ABDOUS"):
    '''Whenever the the backup drive is inserted this function is triggered'''

    if drive.label != backup_drive:
        return
    logger.info('Backup drive has been plugged in')
    logger.info(f'Backing up {drive.letter}')


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    # print(list_drives())
    listener = DeviceListener(on_change=on_devices_changed)
    listener.start()
```

Abdussamet Koçak made a script for monitoring USB Drives which is really close to what I needed for monitoring DVDs and modifiy to suit my needs. https://abdus.dev/posts/python-monitor-usb/